# MySQL query nested query

Tags: php, mysql

I`m trying to run a nested query on MySQL (phpmyadmin) and via PHP, and both result in the same output which is incorrect.

NOTE: Table name have been clipped due to sensitivity of project

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE ID="SELECT `field1` FROM `table2` WHERE ID=1"
```

This returns zero rows, although each query alone gives a valid output as below

```
SELECT `field1` FROM `table2` WHERE ID=1
```

Gives the required output, and this output when used in the first part of the main query provides also what is required. Please help.

Comment: Must be *very* sensitive if the table name alone can give it away. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't enclose it in quotes. Instead enclose it in parentheses:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE ID=(SELECT `field1` FROM `table2` WHERE ID=1)
```

If multiple rows are expected from the subquery, use `WHERE ID IN (SELECT...)` instead of `WHERE ID=(SELECT...)`

You'll probably get better performance with a `JOIN` though:

```
SELECT table1.* 
FROM
  table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.field1
WHERE table1.ID = 1
```

Comment: just figured it out :). Thanks. I'll mark as correct answer in two minutes (rules here)

Answer (score 2):

Your nested query is wrong, it should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE ID in (SELECT `field1` FROM `table2` WHERE ID=1)
```

In your case, you're comparing table1.ID with a string containing the second query.