# Running a mysql query multiple times using values from an array in the WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

I need to run a database query multiple times depending in the User ID. Heres my query:

```
    $query1="INSERT INTO wp_scloyalty (userid, value) VALUES ('XXXXX', '01234')";
```

I have an array of user ID's from a seperate query shown here:

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($allresult)){  

    $birthdays_today[] = $rows['user_id']; 

}

echo $birthdays_today[0];
```

I want the query to run, but there the "userid" = XXXXX in the query, I want that to be populated with a user ID from the array. This means the query must be ran multiple times and each time, the next ID is entered into the query..

Does this make sense?

Thanks :)

Comment: It looks like you might want to use a nested query.  If you want the '01234' to be the same value for all of the userId values. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581930/mysql-query-nested-query

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has a bulk insert feature.

`$query1="INSERT INTO wp_scloyalty (userid, value) VALUES ('XXXXX', '01234'), ('XXX2', '23234'), ('XXXX3', '3434545')"`

```
<?php
$query = "INSERT INTO wp_scloyalty (userid, value) VALUES ";
$usersToInsert = array();
foreach($birthdays_today as $user_id){
    $usersToInsert[] = "($user_id, '01234')";
}
$query .= implode(',', $usersToInsert);
?>
```

Comment: Could even get rid of the loop all together with implode :)

Comment: Oh wait, how would that work since we need a value for loyalty too?

Comment: Well, it depends if the OP wants 01234 to change or not. If he doesn't you could just set the separater as ', '01234'),('

Comment: Ah yeah, I see now. Pretty clever.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop and change out the query with sprintf() and string formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach($birthdays_today as $uid){
    mysql_query(); // ...
}
?>
```

but

```
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($allresult)){  
    mysql_query(); // use $rows['user_id'] here
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will only display the script after your `$birthdays_today[]` has been populated.

```
foreach( $birthdays_today as $thisID )
{
  mysql_query( "INSERT INTO wp_scloyalty (userid, value) VALUES ('{$thisID}', '01234');" );
}
```